# how to use threads in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

In javascript I am trying to collect a response in variable and print it.  It will print the variable undefind and then print the response.  It will first print the servicedata =undefined
 then it will print the response which is retrieved from the server.

```
var data = get(requiredUrl);
console.log('servicedata ='+jsonstr);
```

I think it is not waiting for the response and execute the statement below it.  For that I have to use threads; how can I do this in javascript?

```
function get(partenerUrl) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', partenerUrl, true);

    xhr.send(null);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log('in onreadystatechange:' + xhr.readyState + 'status'
                + xhr.status);

        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var arrayOfObjects = eval(xhr.responseText);
            var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(arrayOfObjects)
            console.log('response>>' + jsonstr);
            return jsonstr;
        }
        return NETWORK_CONNECTION_NOT_FOUND;
    }

}
```

Comment: "For that I have to use threads" No, you don't.

Comment: You have to use AJAX. Ajax !== threads.

Comment: @Panagiotis: AJAX = Asynchronous... = concurrent = a form of threading (green threads, if you want to put it like that)

Comment: Yes, true. but not in the way @user1093591 means it.

Comment: @Panagiotis: Your comment speaks in absolutes. By the way, this can also be done synchronously, so you don't have to use AJAX, like you stated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things wrong here. The variable `jsonstr` is declared inside your `get` function, so it is not even accessible for your `console.log('servicedata ='+jsonstr);` call.

But that would not work anyways because you are correct, the call is asynchronous and as such, the line will execute immediately. You need to call the `console.log` inside of your `get` function. Which you already do with `console.log('response>>' + jsonstr);`. So don't really see what the problem is?

PS - this has nothing to do with threads.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, first you do

```
console.log('servicedata ='+jsonstr);
```

instead of

```
console.log('servicedata =' + data);
```

Also, a you make a a(as asynchronous)jax query here

```
 xhr.open('GET', partenerUrl, true /* The `true` here mean asynchronous`*/);
```

So the script will not wait the xhr.onreadystatechange callback to continue, the get method will never send you anything. If you want to get the actual data, you will have to do it inside the xhr.onreadystatechange callback, or (and it's a bad choice) set the asynchronous parameter to false, but it will eventually freeze a little bit your application.